# ace x markdown editor not working for joomla 3.2? alternatives?

Tags: joomla, syntax-highlighting, markdown, joomla-extensions, joomla3.2

[So I installed the ace x markdown editor plugin for joomla 3.2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/24297) because it has a nice feature to insert code snippets in stackoverflow style. So I really need that.

I tried this extension, but it seems to not work. Is there an alternative?

But: There is no documentation, it seems I just have to enable it and hope it works. But it just happens nothing, the normal editor shows up:

No errors, but old editor:
[image: old editor of joomla showing instead of markdown editor]
the plugins are installed:
[image: plugin installed of acex markdown]

The plugin is supposed to look like this:
[image: ace x markdown editor broken?]

Comment: have you tried contacting the developer of this extension?

Comment: I wrote something to his forum, but the forum has so little activity? I think before I get an answer I am turning bald. Btw it is here: http://ext.asikart.com/discussions/extension-not-working-for-joomla-3-2.html

Answer (score 1):

The second step you have to do is going to: Global configuration area and select the new editor, then if you save your changes and the old editor still appearing, it could be because your profile has the older one selected... in this case you have to go to your user details page and select the new editor or put into default.